# Dockercompose can't access using hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost

I am quite new to docker but am trying to use docker compose to run automation tests against my application.

I have managed to get docker compose to run my application and run my automation tests, however, at the moment my application is running on `localhost` when I need it to run against a specific domain `example.com`.

From research into docker it seems you should be able to hit the application on the hostname by setting it within `links`, but I still don't seem to be able to.

Below is the code for my docker compose files...

docker-compose.yml

```
abc:
  build: ./
  command: run container-dev
  ports:
    - "443:443"
  expose:
    - "443"
```

docker-compose.automation.yml

```
tests:
  build: test/integration/
  dockerfile: DockerfileUIAuto
  command: sh -c "Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &>xvfb.log && sleep 20 && DISPLAY=:1.0 && ENVIRONMENT=qa BASE_URL=https://example.com npm run automation"
  links:
    - abc:example.com
  volumes:
    - /tmp:/tmp/
```

and am using the following command to run...

```
docker-compose -p tests -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.automation.yml up --build
```

Is there something I'm missing to map `example.com` to `localhost`?

Comment: Have you try add `network_mode: host` to your docker-compose services?

Comment: This actually seemed to solve it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the two containers are on the same Docker internal network, Docker will provide a DNS service where one can talk to the other by just its container name.  As you show this with two separate `docker-compose.yml` files it's a little tricky, because Docker Compose wants to isolate each file into its own separate mini-Docker world.

The first step is to [explicitly declare a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference) in the "first" `docker-compose.yml` file.  By default Docker Compose will automatically create a network for you, but you need to control its name so that you can refer to it from elsewhere.  This means you need a top-level `networks:` block, and also to attach the container to the network.

```
version: '3'
networks:
  abc:
    name: abc
services:
  abc:
    build: ./
    command: run container-dev
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      abc:
        aliases:
          - example.com
```

Then in your test file, you can import that as an [external](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) network.

```
version: 3
networks:
  abc:
    external: true
    name: abc
services:
  tests:
    build: test/integration/
    dockerfile: DockerfileUIAuto
    command: sh -c "Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &>xvfb.log && sleep 20 && npm run automation"
    environment:
      DISPLAY: "1.0"
      ENVIRONMENT: qa
      BASE_URL: "https://example.com"
    networks:
      - abc
```

Given the complexity of what you're showing for the "test" container, I would strongly consider running it not in Docker, or else writing a shell script that launches the X server, checks that it actually started, and then runs the test.  The `docker-compose.yml` file isn't the only tool you have here.